# Querying a LinqToSql result

Tags: vb.net, linq

Let's say I have a Persons table with two columns:

- ID (Uniqueidentifier)
- Name (NChar)

I need to get all my persons first:

```
Dim data = (From p In Persons Select p).ToList
```

Now that I got all persons in the data variable, is it possible to query this result using a string query? Like...

```
Dim filtered = (From p In data Select p).Where("Name Like '%John%').ToList
```

?

I need to build the query on the fly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = data.Where(a => 
                              SqlMethods.Like(a.name.ToString(), "%" +    
                               Request.QueryString["search"] + "%"));
```

i use querystring as an example for dynamic value, and use it in sql like method,
which is similiar to sql like, in your case "request.querystring["search"] value is john"

Comment: This looks open to SQL injection?

Comment: i just answered his question, to prevent the sql injection, then put some extra validation for the querystring variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from p in data
where SqlMethods.Like(p.Name, "%"+parameter+"%")
select p;
```

**parameter** in your example should be **John**.

Comment: if you hardcode the parameter to "john" from the start, so what's the point of  build the query on the fly?

Comment: @Renato ... thanks ... let's say my table also had "Birthday", how would I select Name=John and Birthday between 1-1-2010 and 31-12-2010? In my real app, the customer provides the search criteria, så I actually don't know the fields up front - therefor I need to build the "select" on the fly. :)

Comment: From p In Data Where p.Name = name And (p.Date >= startDate And p.Date <= endDate) Select p